# "Deemed Invalid" doesn't have a name attached on the flagged posts page

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, flags

There is no name attached to the "Deemed Invalid" line. Should there be? All the other actions are anonymous, is this one supposed to list the moderator name? (Should this even be visible since a mod handled it or is it just a caching issue?)

[image: deemed invalid]

Comment: note the bug in the screen shot is fixed ... it now says "deemed invalid by 1 user"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "deemed invalid by" flag is not a moderator action - it's a specific flag action taken by other users. If a moderator deems flags invalid, it gets dismissed and you won't see it on that page (at least, until it gets flagged again). I'll borrow this image yet again to illustrate:

[image: flag as invalid]

So in the same vein that other flags do not have names attached, nor will "These flags are invalid" flags have names attached. Their contrasting display is meant to highlight the fact that the flags are contested.

Comment: Oh right, forgot about that flag. So I take it that instead of saying "by (username)" it is supposed to say "by 1 user" or "by 2 users", similar to the way "not an answers" are now grouped together?

Comment: @Brandon I guess. The sites where I have visibility to this, there ain't all that much disagreement in flags.